# JMeter - Throughput Controller random execution instead of sequential execution

Tags: jmeter

I have about 10 Throughput Controllers with different percentages and I have 100 users.  During the load test, it always have the 100 users run the first Controller followed by the second.  This loads up the first backend transaction while the rest are not run yet.

Is there a way to run the different controllers randomly but still abide by the percentage set in the Throughtput Controller spreading the load ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "different percentages" given the number of users is 100 the number of users executing the first controller's children should be equal to the percentage set in the [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller).

Demo:

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter), it's easier to configure and you won't have to copy and paste and maintain all these Throughput Controllers, the configuration will be done in only one place.